# Exception handling in lambda function?

Tags: python, exception, lambda

I have following Python code for a language detection library, applied to a pandas DataFrame:

```
df['check'].apply(lambda x: detect(str(x)) else np.nan)
```

So the row in the new column `check` should be `np.nan` if `detect(str(x))` does not work (exception).

However, the code responds

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I add a correct exception statement to the lambda line?

Thanks in advance!

––

After the comments below, I solved it as follows:

```
def lang_func(x):
    try:
        language = detect(str(x))
    except:
        language = np.nan
    return language

df['check'] = df['text'].apply(lang_func)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use something like `x if some_condition else y`? `else` without `if` means nothing... But you can't use that if you get an exception.

Comment: You can't catch exceptions in a lambda-expression. Use a full function instead.

Comment: it's not `else` it's `or`

Comment: Ah, so there's no way to deal with exceptions in a lambda function?

Comment: @diggusbickus or doesn't work either, when the main function throws an error.

Comment: at least it's the correct idiom

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use the ternary conditional operator, but the syntax  is wrong. The correct syntax is

```
a if condition else b
```

Thus, you cannot use the expression

```
detect(str(x)) else np.nan
```

I'm just guessing, but perhaps you want

```
x if detect(str(x)) else np.nan
```

This expression would evaluate to `x` if the `detect()` returns `True` and else to `np.nan`.

Comment: `apply(lambda x: x if detect(str(x)) else np.nan)` doesn't work. Just stops when detect() throws an error.

Comment: As noted above, you cannot handle exceptions in lambdas. If you want to use a lambda, wrap `detect()` in another function and handle the expection there.

Comment: `[detect(str(x)) for x in df.text]` would not allow that either, correct?

Comment: No, you cannot handle exceptions inside a list comprehension either. Of course you can wrap the whole comprehension in a `try` block, but it will still terminate when the function hits an exception. If you expect exceptions, it's best not to use shorthands such as listcomps or lambdas.